# Read information from Outlook emails

Tags: c#, object-oriented

This class is read specific information(body, subject...) form Outlook emails.
I want some suggestions(Naming, avoid code smells, OOP designs.. and more..) to improve this code... Thanks.

```
public class MailMessageInfoHandler
{
    private const string ExchangeAddressType = "EX",
                         SmtpAddressType = "SMTP";

    private readonly MailItem[] emails;

    public MailMessageInfoHandler(MailItem[] emails)
    {
        if (emails == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Write some error message...", nameof(emails));
        }
        else
        {
            if (emails.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Write some error message...", nameof(emails));
            }
        }

        this.emails = emails;
    }

    private MailItem[] Emails
    {
        get { return this.emails; }
    }

    public MailMessageInfo[] GetMailMessageInfos()
    {
        var emailInfos = new MailMessageInfo[Emails.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < Emails.Length; i++)
        {
            emailInfos[i] = GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail(Emails[i]);
        }

        return emailInfos;
    }

    private MailMessageInfo GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail(MailItem email)
    {
        var emailInfo = new MailMessageInfo();

        try
        {
            emailInfo.AdresseeEmailAddress = GetAddresseEmailAddresses(email);
            emailInfo.AttachedFiles = GetAttachments(email);
            emailInfo.Body = email.Body;
            emailInfo.DownloadTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            emailInfo.EmailMessageId = email.EntryID;
            emailInfo.SenderEmailAddress = GetSenderEmailAddress(email);
            emailInfo.SenderName = email.SenderName;
            emailInfo.Subject = email.Subject;
        }
        catch (System.Exception exception)
        {
            emailInfo.ErrorText = exception.Message;
        }

        return emailInfo;
    }

    private string GetSenderEmailAddress(MailItem email)
    {
        var emailAddress = string.Empty;

        switch (email.SenderEmailType)
        {
            case ExchangeAddressType:
                AddressEntry sender = email.Sender;

                if (sender != null && (sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry || sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry))
                {
                    var exchangeUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
                    if (exchangeUser != null)
                    {
                        emailAddress = exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                    }
                }

                break;

            case SmtpAddressType:
                emailAddress = email.SenderEmailAddress;
                break;
        }

        return emailAddress;
    }

    private string[] GetAddresseEmailAddresses(MailItem outlookEmail)
    {
        var emailAddresses = new List<string>();

        foreach (Recipient recipient in outlookEmail.Recipients)
        {
            switch (recipient.AddressEntry.Type)
            {
                case ExchangeAddressType:
                    var exchangeUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                    if (exchangeUser != null)
                    {
                        emailAddresses.Add(exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress);
                    }

                    break;

                case SmtpAddressType:
                    emailAddresses.Add(recipient.AddressEntry.Address);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return emailAddresses.ToArray();
    }

    private MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile[] GetAttachments(MailItem email)
    {
        var attachmentCount = email.Attachments.Count;

        if (attachmentCount > 0)
        {
            var attachments = new MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile[attachmentCount];
            var attachment = new MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile();

            for (int i = 1; i <= attachmentCount; i++)
            {
                attachment = new MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile();

                attachment.Data = GetAttachmentData(email.Attachments[i]);
                attachment.FileName = email.Attachments[i].FileName;
                attachment.MimeType = GetAttachmentMimeTag(email.Attachments[i]);

                attachments[i - 1] = attachment;
            }

            return attachments;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private string GetAttachmentMimeTag(Attachment attachment)
    {
        const string AttachmentMimePropTag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370e001e";

        var accessProperty = attachment.PropertyAccessor;
        return (string)accessProperty.GetProperty(AttachmentMimePropTag);
    }

    private byte[] GetAttachmentData(Attachment attachment)
    {
        const string AttachmentDataPropTag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

        var accessProperty = attachment.PropertyAccessor;
        return (byte[])accessProperty.GetProperty(AttachmentDataPropTag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MailMessageInfoHandler` is, I think, a misleading name. Your class does not *handle* anything, it translates from one entity to another. It *maps* or *convert* `MailItem` to `MailMessageInfo`.

Class should be `sealed`, there isn't any extension point (so far). It's easy to remove it if/when you will need but it may be impossible to add it later without breaking class contract.

Constructor accepts `MailItem[]` but you simply iterate through them, you should really accept `IEnumerable<MailItem>` instead (it leaves more flexibility at calling point).

When a parameter is `null` you should throw the more specific `ArgumentNullException` instead of generic `ArgumentException`.

You might consider to accept an empty enumeration instead of throwing `ArgumentException`. I do not think it's responsibility of a *conversion object* to validate business logic and from its point of view an empty list is a perfectly valid input.

Private property `EMails` adds nothing over the private field `emails`, just use the field and drop the property.

Order public/private methods as you prefer (public/private or private/public) but pick one order and stick to it, do not mix public and private declarations because it makes much harder to inspect class interface (and implementation) without jumping here and there in the code.

`GetMailMessageInfos()` might be simplified:

```
public MailMessageInfo[] GetMailMessageInfos()
    => this.emails.Select(x => GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail(x)).ToArray();
```

In `GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail()` you're catching `Exception`. It's a very bad practice, catch only the exceptions you know may happen and nothing else. Also (from your revised code) do not ever catch exceptions you may avoid (such as `NullReferenceException` and `ArgumentException`), check the preconditions and act accordingly (yes, I know, it's a programming style encouraged in other languages but not in C#).

`GetSenderEmailAddress()` may be simplified, `switch` over two conditions might be rewritten to use `if`:

```
private string GetSenderEmailAddress(MailItem email)
{
    if (email.SenderEmailType == AddressType.SmtpAddressType)
        return email.SenderEmailAddress;

    if (email.Sender == null)
        return null;

    bool isExchangeAddress = email.Sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
        || email.Sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)

    if (!isExchangeAddress)
        return null;

    return email.Sender.GetExchangeUser()?.PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

Note that I'm trying to remove indentation to make code easier to read. The same apply to `GetAddresseEmailAddresses()` as well. One quick highlight:

```
 foreach (Recipient recipient in email.Recipients)
 {
    if (email.SenderEmailType == SmtpAddressType)
        emailAddresses.Add(email.SenderEmailAddress);

    if (email.Sender == null)
        continue;

    // ...
 }
```

In `GetAttachments()` you should do the same, if list is empty simply return immediately:

```
if (email.Attachments.Count == 0)
    return null;
```

I do not remember the type of `email.Attachments` but you may also do:

```
if (!email.Attachments.Any())
    return null;
```

It's the same but it makes the intent more clear (at least to me).

`GetAttachmentMimeTag()` and `GetAttachmentData()` might be static.

You, usually, do not need to validate inputs for private methods but I find very useful to add `Debug.Assert()` to assert about preconditions. Very often it helped me to spot out errors I didn't cover in my unit testing...when I was running the test on my dev machine (then compiling in debug).

Final note, do not save few characters when defining fields. One field per line:

```
private const string ExchangeAddressType = "EX";
private const string SmtpAddressType = "SMTP";
```

This is less an issue in C# than, let's say, in C but it saves you to try to keep visual alignment using spaces. Isn't it a bigger effort?

Comment: _Class should be sealed_ - should it? I never do that ;-] what would be the benefit?

Comment: @t3chb0t don't you? :O LOL well, from a pragmatic point of view I'd say that if you're not writing _libraries_ (in a very broad sense, from someone else in your team to someone outside your organization) then it doesn't really matter (I'd bet compiler does not optimize anything because of that). If, instead, you're writing a _library_ then it helps to restrict the contract you expose. After you started to _use_ it then it's just an habit, regardless who will see/use your code

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@AdrianoRepetti's suggestions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/172685/59161) I find that the only `public` method you have there, the `GetMailMessageInfos`, does not require an instance. It could be just an extension  for the `MailItem[]` collection and it could be implemented purely with LINQ in a lazy fashion:

```
public static IEnumerable<MailMessageInfo> GetMailMessageInfos(this IEnumerable<MailItem> mailItems)
{
    return
        from mi in mailItems
        select GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail(mi);
}
```

or because the `GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail` takes exactly one argument, which is a `MailItem` you could use it with the other syntax and put it inside a `Select` so it would be a oneliner.

```
return mailItems.Select(GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Based on your suggestions I try to rewrite the class.
Here is the new version:

```
public sealed class MailItemConverter
{
    private const string ExchangeAddressType = "EX";
    private const string SmtpAddressType = "SMTP";
    private readonly IEnumerable<MailItem> emails;

    public MailItemConverter(IEnumerable<MailItem> emails)
    {
        if (emails == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(emails), "Write some error message...");
        }

        this.emails = emails;
    }

    public MailMessageInfo[] GetMailMessageInfos()
        => this.emails.Select(x => GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail(x)).ToArray();

    private MailMessageInfo GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail(MailItem email)
    {
        var emailInfo = new MailMessageInfo();
        try
        {
            emailInfo.AdresseeEmailAddress = GetAddresseEmailAddresses(email);
            emailInfo.AttachedFiles = GetAttachments(email);
            emailInfo.Body = email.Body;
            emailInfo.DownloadTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            emailInfo.EmailMessageId = email.EntryID;
            emailInfo.SenderEmailAddress = GetSenderEmailAddress(email);
            emailInfo.SenderName = email.SenderName;
            emailInfo.Subject = email.Subject;
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException exception)
        {
            emailInfo.ErrorText = exception.Message;
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception)
        {
            if (emailInfo.ErrorText.Length > 0)
                emailInfo.ErrorText += System.Environment.NewLine;
            emailInfo.ErrorText += exception.Message;
        }

        return emailInfo;
    }

    private string GetSenderEmailAddress(MailItem email)
    {
        if (email.SenderEmailType == SmtpAddressType)
            return email.SenderEmailAddress;

        if (email.Sender == null)
            return null;

        bool isExchangeAddress = email.Sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            || email.Sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry;

        if (!isExchangeAddress)
            return null;

        return email.Sender.GetExchangeUser()?.PrimarySmtpAddress;
    }

    private string[] GetAddresseEmailAddresses(MailItem email)
    {
        var emailAddresses = new List<string>();

        foreach (Recipient recipient in email.Recipients)
        {
            if (email.SenderEmailType == SmtpAddressType)
                emailAddresses.Add(email.SenderEmailAddress);

            if (email.Sender != null)
            {
                bool isExchangeAddress = email.Sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
                    || email.Sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry;

                if (isExchangeAddress)
                {
                    string exchangeAddress = email.Sender.GetExchangeUser()?.PrimarySmtpAddress;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exchangeAddress))
                        emailAddresses.Add(exchangeAddress);
                }
            }
        }

        return emailAddresses.ToArray();
    }

    private MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile[] GetAttachments(MailItem email)
    {
        var attachmentCount = email.Attachments.Count;

        if (attachmentCount == 0)
            return null;

        var attachments = new MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile[attachmentCount];
        MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile attachment;

        for (int i = 1; i <= attachmentCount; i++)
        {
            attachment = new MailMessageInfo.AttachedFile();

            attachment.Data = GetAttachmentData(email.Attachments[i]);
            attachment.FileName = email.Attachments[i].FileName;
            attachment.MimeType = GetAttachmentMimeTag(email.Attachments[i]);

            attachments[i - 1] = attachment;
        }

        return attachments;
    }

    private static string GetAttachmentMimeTag(Attachment attachment)
    {
        const string AttachmentMimePropTag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370e001e";

        var accessProperty = attachment.PropertyAccessor;
        return (string)accessProperty.GetProperty(AttachmentMimePropTag);
    }

    private static byte[] GetAttachmentData(Attachment attachment)
    {
        const string AttachmentDataPropTag = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

        var accessProperty = attachment.PropertyAccessor;
        return (byte[])accessProperty.GetProperty(AttachmentDataPropTag);
    }
}
```

In `GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail` for error handling should I use exception filter or multiple catch?

Comment: If you have a new version you want to be reviewed then post it as a new question (linking back to the previous one), do not post an answer.

Comment: I'd wait with posting any improved versions yet... the question is only 3h old so it's very likely that you'll get more answers.

Comment: If the class name now is Converter, why not take it further and adapt the method names accordingly? For e.g : GetEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail to ConvertEmailInfoFromOutlookEmail? I would even take it further by encapsulating this logic to a new constructor in MailMessageInfo, where it accepts a MailItem object and builds the MailMessageInfo details from it.